# List to string with prepended static text (performance, most pythonic)

Tags: python, performance

I have a list of labels (`['aa', 'bb', 'cc']`) that I want to make into a string (`label=aa label=bb label=cc`). This is trivial, but I want performance, and a pythonic way to do this.

What I currently have is this;

```
In [1]: timeit ''.join([ 'label={} '.format(i) for i in ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 us per loop
```

and this

```
In [2]: timeit 'label=' + ' label='.join(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']) + ' '
1000000 loops, best of 3: 346 ns per loop
```

They both produce the same string, but the 2nd one, which I feel like is a very non-pythonic way of doing this is much faster.

Is there a better, more pythonic way that wont hurt my heart?

Comment: The second way seems pretty pythonic to me, and in fact it would have been my recommendation to do it like that, when i saw the preview of the post without the snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Does this counts?

```
l = ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
('label=%s '*len(l)) % l
```

timeit gives

```
timeit ('label=%s ' * len(l)) % l
1000000 loops, best of 3: 263 ns per loop
```

Comment: Nice one :) When I run them both, I'm getting about the exact same per loop. +/- 5ns.. Hard to measure :]

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt you are going to find a faster way than the second,
this one might look more 'pythonic' to you, but your second one is still 3 times as fast as this:

```
''.join(map(lambda z: 'label=' + z + ' ', ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']))
```

And the results:

```
python -m timeit "''.join(map(lambda z: 'label=' + z + ' ', ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 usec per loop

python -m timeit "'label=' + ' label='.join(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']) + ' '"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.361 usec per loop
```